# Submitting a Form Action Post for API, do I need a post route?

Tags: node.js, forms, twitter, express

I am using the npm ["twit"](https://github.com/ttezel/twit) and it is ultimately posting Twitter Status Updates. I have the user fill out a form and the action of the form is a post request to a path like `home/tweet/`.

In my express router I have a route `home/tweet/`.  The Form data isn't really being posted there though, the reason I am doing this is because I am extracting the form fields qith req.body and then inside the router I am making the post request to Twitter to create a new tweet. Here is what it looks like:

```
router.post("/tweet/", function(req,res){
    var tweet = req.body.tweet;
    Twitter.post('statuses/update', { status: myFuncs.encode(myFuncs.key, tweet) }, function(err, data, response) {

    });
    res.redirect('/');
})
```

Even though this works, it feels a little hacky to me.  Is there a better way to design this? Is there a better way to extract the Form Fields without using a post request using `req.body`, or a get request using `req.query`?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want your code to essentially look like as if when the user sends the tweet via your form, the tweet is sent out directly to Twitter? I'm asking, because I think I have an answer but I might be answering to the wrong question.

Comment: Yes, currently the "post" route isn't posting data anywhere. It is more or less grabbing the dat from the req.body.  Then after it grabs the data it is posted to twitter.  This just seems a little hacky to me, I feel like I should just be able to post straight to twitter without having to make this additional post request route just to grab the user req.body.

Comment: I see the benefit behind it, because this prevents an additional roundtrip (the client to server, then server to twitter, and back), but it seems as though Twitter has not enabled [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) on its API.

Comment: And so, you *will* have to settle with your current method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although, I agree that it seems "hacky"---as you put it---but unfortunately, since Twitter has not enabled [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) on its API, you have no choice *but* to use an intermediary, such as your server. Alternatively, you may use a third-party service, but that *still* is an intermediary just like your server.